# Is there a shorthand way to initialise more than one private instance variable?

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorthand way to initialise more than one private instance variable?

```js
class Foo {
    #bar
    #bam
    constructor(o) {
        Object.assign(this, o) // not valid
    }
}

const f = new Foo({ '#bar': 'this is bar', '#bam': 'this is bam' })
```

Comment: What is an "instance variable"? That doesn't look like valid javascript syntax. If you are using an experimental proposal, please state which.

Comment: What is the shorthand you found to initialise exactly one of these?

Comment: By instance variable, I mean a per-instance private field.

Comment: To initialise one it would be `this.#foo = ‘foo’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are basing your code on the [Class field declarations for JavaScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) (specifically, [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#private-fields)):

> There are no private computed property names: `#foo` is a private identifier, and `#[foo]` is a syntax error.

Also see the [private syntax FAQ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/master/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-doesnt-thisx-access-the-private-field-named-x-given-that-thisx-does):

> ## Why doesn't this['#x'] access the private field named #x, given that this.#x does?
>
> 1. This would complicate property access semantics.
> 2. Dynamic access to private fields is contrary to the notion of 'private'. E.g. this is concerning:
>
> ```
> class Dict extends null {
>   #data = something_secret;
>   add(key, value) {
>     this[key] = value;
>   }
>   get(key) {
>     return this[key];
>   }
> }
> (new Dict).get('#data'); // returns something_secret
> ```
>
> ### But doesn't giving this.#x and this['#x'] different semantics break an invariant of current syntax?
>
> Not exactly, but it is a concern. this.#x has never previously been
>   legal syntax, so from one point of view there can be no invariant
>   regarding it.
>
> On the other hand, it might be surprising that they differ, and this
>   is a downside of the current proposal.

You cannot dynamically access private fields like you can with normal properties. As far as I know, there is thus no way to achieve what you want to do.

In addition, it seems rather strange that the outside code knows about and tries to define *private* fields. Maybe you should use `get`/`set` instead?

Comment: To your last point: it does seem strange at first, but actually, I could see it being pretty useful, and I don’t think it really breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @52d6c6af It certainly breaks encapsulation! The entire point of a private property is *specifically* that it can only be accessed by code internal to the class. To simply go and allow any means of accessing it like a normal property would entirely defeat the purpose.

Comment: It doesn’t break encapsulation, because you cannot directly set or read the field. If the implementor of the class chooses to assign an inbound field to the inner private field, then so be it, but the caller has no way of knowing this, and encapsulation remains in effect.

Comment: @52d6c6af but it's not the implementor of this class assigning the private field, in your example in the question it's `Object.assign()` doing the assigning - breaking encapsulation.

Comment: The `Object.assign` is inside the constructor. The class itself is choosing to use a shorthand to map arguments to internal fields. From the outside, no one knows about this: they just see the parameter list. Encapsulation is maintained.

Comment: @52d6c6af `Object.assign()` is a function. It contains code that iterates the second parameter, assigning each property to the first parameter (presumably). If that code were able to access the first object's *private* members, they wouldn't be private members by definition. Remember that `Object.assign()` counts as external code to your class.

Comment: I think our wires are crossed. I wanted a shorthand way to map public properties on `o` to private instance fields on `Foo`, from inside `Foo`‘s constructor.