# Can a private method of a JavaScript class be accessed dynamically?

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, private

Suppose I have a class in Javascript as follows:

```
class T {
   #p() {
   }
   a(s) {
     this['#'+s]();
   }
}
t = new T();
```

My intention is that when I call `t.a('p')`, `#p` would be called in return. However, this doesn't work, and a debug shows that `this['#p']` is undefined within `a`. Public methods work fine using this method, so I was wondering if there is anyway to invoke a private method within a class method based on its name dynamically.

Thanks!

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710798/is-there-a-shorthand-way-to-initialise-more-than-one-private-instance-variable/60712334#60712334

Comment: This seems to work ```eval(`this.#${s}()`)```

Comment: @str So strong in fact that I think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @deceze Agreed. I tried looking for a specification specifically about methods but did not find anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot @str, I had searched for a potential answer but had not stumbled upon this. It is weird that this is not in the specification but somehow in some hidden github doc. The behavior is also weird but what can one do.. :-)

Comment: Private fields and methods are still just a proposal. So they are not yet official languages features but most probably will be soon (maybe already in the next version of ECMAScript).